# Estimating a parameter from a sequence of signals with non i.i.d. noise

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation

I have the following statistics/probability question:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets of real numbers. Let $n \geq 1$. Let $T_1,...,T_n$ be random variables with values in $A$ (not necessarily independent). Let $Q$ be a random variable with values in $B$. 
Let $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,...,\epsilon_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables which are identically normally distributed, with mean 0 and variance $\sigma>0$. Assume that
for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, $\epsilon_i$ is independent of $T_i$ and of $Q$ (note that $\epsilon_i$ may be correlated with $T_{i-1}$ for instance). Let
\begin{equation*}
X_i=T_i+Q+\epsilon_i
\end{equation*}
I would like to construct a random variable $Q_n$ that is $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$-measurable, and such that for some constant $C$ and $d>0$ that depend only on $A$, $B$ and $\sigma$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\left\|Q_n-Q\right\|_{L^2} \leq C n^{-d}.
\end{equation*}
In words, knowing $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, I would like to approximate $Q$ in an efficient way.

Many thanks!